# Cognos - value prompt to display months from january to december

Tags: cognos-11, report-studio

For a monthly report need to display the months January to December in the value prompt. Could you please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: I am new to Cognos tool and any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far.  Let us know more about the tools being used.  What version of Cognos?  what database?  are you using DQM?  This will help us adjust for specific functions/capabilities available to you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Immi

I do not know what data items are available on the package you are using

However, you can create static values with a value prompt
Look in properties for the value prompt, static.  Select the ellipsis
Then add the values

Depending on the version of Cognos, you can search the data items (worst case do this manually, maybe you will luck out and there is a query subject for dates).  Look around and see if months is in the package.  If they exist, add them to the value prompt query subject and give it a try

Also to consider, your take may require 13 month accounting, displaying the month name won't work in that case.

As far as value prompts there is a display value and a use value
The month name can be the display value and if you need for filtering the month #, that can be the use value.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/opw/8.0.0?topic=prompts-adding-static-choices-prompt

Comment: Thanks for the input Jason. I am using Cognos Analytics v12. Months do not exist in the package and leaning on extracting the month number for the current date. I might have to do a case statement to create the static values for the months..  Will try your recommendation and see if I can make it work.

Comment: No case statement, no query needed.  See link that I added.  Create a value prompt.  Enter the 12 entries and you are done.  If you share more about the data, I might be able to give suggestions for that as well.  For example, you mention you do not have months, you may want to add a table that converts dates to different groupings

Comment: Any luck with the suggestion?